# Update column and instantly use result to update second column within same statement

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

In Oracle SQL (version 12c) is there a way of performing an update on multiple columns referencing each other? Assuming I have the following table named **test_tb**:

```
|pk  |col1|col2|
----------------
|1   |4   |1   |
|2   |9   |2   |
|3   |7   |9   |
```

I intend to achieve the following result:

```
|pk  |col1|col2|
----------------
|1   |5   |6   |
|2   |10  |12  |
|3   |8   |17  |
```

By first setting

```
col1 = col1 + 1
```

followed by

```
col2 = col2 + col1
```

As far as I am aware I can do this:

```
update test_tb set col1 = col1 + 1, col2 = col2 + col1 + 1
```

However, when doing more complex operations this will become high maintanance. Another option is:

```
merge into test_tb desc
using (
  with tmp as (
    select pk,
      col1 + 1 as col1,
      col2
    from test_tb
  )
  select pk,
    col1,
    col2 + col1 as col2
) src
on (dest.pk = src.pk)
when matched then update set
  dest.col1 = src.col1,
  dest.col2 = src.col1;
```

With a lot of data (my table has ~10 mio. rows) this is not an option performance wise.

Is there any way of not having to write the code resulting in "col1" twice and also having a good performance at the same time?

Comment: How often are you going to want to do this? Updating COL2 with the updated value of COL1 sounds like a really odd data model. I'm intrigued to know what the business logic really is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could update an inline view, perhaps? E.g.:

```
update (select pk,
               col1,
               col2,
               col1 + 1 col1_new
        from   your_table)
set col1 = col1_new,
    col2 = col2 + col1_new;
```

[Full test case](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f0f5122809dd99358492c73c41f75a1d)

Comment: Great, this works! By any chance: Would you also know if there is a way to additionally parallelize this? I already tried to add a /*+ parallel */ hint after update before the ( as well as after select before pk.

Comment: I would imagine you need to do something like the update in https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7dd4cb196d2efd26bcc5cecbc3396233 - i.e. alias the subquery and reference that alias in the parallel hint.